# Sort an array of strings based on length

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

The question is to sort an array of Strings, based on the length of the strings.

For example

```
input = {"cat", "star", "act", "gid", "arts", "dog", "rats"}  
output = {"cat", "act", "gid", "dog", "star", "arts", "rats"}
```

I did it using Insertion sort(using the length of the strings instead of the strings themselves). My question:is there a better way to do it?

An alternative I thought of is - use a `TreeMap` to store each string and its length as value (assume the strings are unique in the given array). Then sort it based on its values. The running time would be `O(nlogn)` and space complexity would be `O(n)`. Do you think this is a better approach?

EDIT: Sorry for not mentioning this earlier - I want to do this without using `Arrays.sort()` or a custom comparator.

Code sample for insertion sort:

```
public static String[] insertionSort(String[] arr) {
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for(;j<i;j++) {
            if(arr[j].length() > arr[j+1].length()) {
                String temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I think expected code will be `O(n)` for both time and space as there is no need to order elements, just initial pass of [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Do I do this using a 2 dimensional string array for the bucket?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal/language is: I'd have map of length to list of strings with that length and fill it out on first iteration, than simply copy all lists together in order. If you know that length of the strings is limited you can use just array or arrays and use first index as key for length, otherwise you'll need to build/use hashtable to get O(1) to add each string to correct sub-array.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Let's assume that I don't know anything about the max/min length of the strings. Assuming my language is Java, your approach seems to be the alternate approach I've given in my question, right?

Comment: Yes, it somewhat different, but my runtime estimate was wrong - if maximum length is not known you'd still have to sort resulting array of length... So your red-black tree approach is as good as my `HashMap` suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of better ways to do it. For insertion sort, we're talking O (n^2). A much better sorting algorithm would be something like mergesort (better worst-case) or quicksort (better on average). Since this is a length-based sort, there are a number of approaches that can be taken. You are going to have to calculate the length of each string at some point. What you could do is create an array of ints that correspond to the lengths of the words at the same respective index. Then you can run mergesort or quicksort on the ints and be sure to flip the strings around at the same time. The end result would be a non-decreasing array of ints and a non-decreasing array of strings.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one.

Your input

```
String[] input = {"cat", "star", "act", "gid", "arts", "dog", "rats"};
```

Your Comparator

```
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return new Integer(o1.length()).compareTo(o2.length());
   }
}
```

Your Sorting

```
Collections.sort(in, new SampleComparator());
```

Your output

```
output = {"cat", "act", "gid", "dog", "star", "arts", "rats"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    String[] str={"umbrella","apple", "baby", "cat","rat","obnoxious"};
    Arrays.sort(str, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a Collection instead (e.g an ArrayList will be great in your case), you can use Collections.sort to do the work for you. It's fast and clean. See: [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

You will need a custom comparator.

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) 
    {
        return s1.length()-s2.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet compiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Comparator as following:

```
public static class OrderStringByLength implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int c = s1.length() - s2.length();
        return (c != 0) ? c : s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the array as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(input, new OrderStringByLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

public class SortArrayOfStringOnLength {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strArray = new String[] { "cat", "star", "act", "gid", "arts",
            "dog", "rats" };

    printArray(strArray);

    String[] outputArray = getSortedArray(strArray);
    printArray(outputArray);

}

private static String[] getSortedArray(String[] strArray) {

    Map map = new TreeMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        String str = strArray[i];
        if (map.containsKey(str.length())) {
            List list = (List) map.get(str.length());
            list.add(str);
            map.put(str.length(), list);
        } else {
            List list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(str);
            map.put(str.length(), list);
        }
    }

    Set set = map.keySet();

    Iterator itr = set.iterator();
    int outArrayIndex = 0;
    String[] outputArray = new String[strArray.length];
    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        Integer intValue = (Integer) itr.next();
        List list = (List) map.get(intValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            outputArray[outArrayIndex] = (String) list.get(i);
            outArrayIndex++;
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}

private static void printArray(String[] strArray) {

    System.out.println("*****************");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(strArray[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] strArray = new String[] { "cat", "star", "act", "gid", "arts",
            "dog", "rats" };
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    strings.sort((s1, s2) -> Math.abs(s1.length()) - Math.abs(s2.length()));
    System.out.println(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: Sort an array of strings according to string lengths.
We can do it Using Streams in Java 8

```
public class SortStringsAccordingToLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> sampleStrings = Arrays.asList("Protijayi", "Gina", "Gini", "Soudipta");

        System.out.println(lengthSortUsingSorted1(sampleStrings));

        System.out.println(lengthSortUsingSorted2(sampleStrings));
        System.out.println(lengthSortUsingSorted3(sampleStrings));
        System.out.println(lengthSortUsingSorted4(sampleStrings));
    }

    private static List<String> lengthSortUsingSorted4(List<String> list) {

        list.sort((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
        System.out.println(list);

        return list;
    }

    private static List<String> lengthSortUsingSorted3(List<String> sampleStrings) {
        List<String> list1 = sampleStrings.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return list1;
    }

    private static List<String> lengthSortUsingSorted2(List<String> sampleStrings) {
        List<String> list1 = sampleStrings.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return list1;
    }

    public static List<String> lengthSortUsingSorted1(List<String> sampleStrings) {
        List<String> list1 = sampleStrings.stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return list1;
    }

}
```